# SQL How to format M/DD/YYYY (1/31/1960) to DD/MM/YYYY (31/01/1969)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a  column that has date and time mixed together i.e. 1/31/1960 12:00:00AM and I would like to convert them into two-column through SQL function:
(a) DD/MM/YYYY i.e 31/01/1969
(b) HH:MM i.e 12:00

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Date and time data types don't have formats; you format it in the **presentation layer**. You can't change it's format in the RDBMS.

Comment: What is the actual data type of the column, and why isn't a datetime value like it should be?

Comment: Why should the formatting change the year...? :P

Comment: So is your "column" a *datetime* or *datetime2* data type. or are you storing your values as (ugh) a string? Please provide more details about what you have and what you expect. You also seem to want to convert between US style dates and rest-of-world proper dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [CONVERT()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp) function, specifically the style for datetime. Additionally, we can [CAST()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp) the DATETIME as a TIME data type to extract the time.

Assuming your original column is a DATETIME data type, you can run

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(24),{DateField},103)
    ,CAST({DateField} AS TIME)
```

If it is string, you can cast it then convert

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(24),CAST('1960-01-31' AS DATETIME),103) AS ReportingDate
    ,CAST(CAST('1960-01-31' AS DATETIME) AS TIME) AS ReportingTime
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a sufficiently recent version of SQL Server, the [FORMAT() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is your friend.

```sql
DECLARE @d DATE = GETDATE();
SELECT FORMAT(@d, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

Note, that second argument is a .NET formatting string, so you should be able to use whatever is available from the Framework.